# Network drops when requesting a page in browser

Tags: linux, linux-mint, wifi-driver

This is a weird one. When I request a page in a browser, I lose network connection. It restores itself and sometimes loads the page after that. This happens in Firefox and Chrome, not in lynx. I can ping sites and other machines on the network, and apt-get upgrade will (slowly) download packages.

From dmesg: `microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x82000000`

Any ideas? I don't even know where to start.

Comment: This might be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1500277 or a kernel issue: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1142917

Comment: Looks like it was a router issue - I was on my schools PEAP network. Not sure why that's causing the error I have, but it's solved I guess.